# Is it possible to implement Live search using AJAX and PHP on elasticsearch index

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, elasticsearch

I am trying to make a web app using PHP & AJAX. It should retrieve data from Elasticsearch without refreshing the page(live search). Is it possible to implement such retrieval on elasticsearch index?
For that, I have made these two files:
index2.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>

<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Ajax-Trials</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <br />
   <h2 align="center">Ajax Live Data Search using Jquery, PHP, Elasticsearch</h2><br />
   <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
     <span class="input-group-addon">Search</span>
     <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" placeholder="Search by Customer Details" class="form-control" />

    </div>
   </div>
   <br />
   <div id="result"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 load_data();

 function load_data(query)
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"fetch2.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{query:query},
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#result').html(data);
   }
  });
 }
 $('#search_text').keyup(function(){
  var search = $(this).val();
  if(search != '')
  {
   load_data(search);
  }
  else
  {
   load_data();
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

and here is fetch2.php

```
<?php    
session_start();    
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;
$client = ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts(['127.0.0.1:9200'])->build();
$output = '';
if(isset($_POST["query"]))
{
 $search = $_POST["query"];
 $query = $client->search([
    'body' => [
      'query' => [
        'bool' => [
          'should' => [
            'multi_match' => [
              "fuzziness" => "AUTO",
              'fields' => ['district','countrycode','name','population'],
              'query' => $search
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ],
      'from' => 0,
      'size' => 100
    ]

  ]);

  if($query['hits']['total']>=1){
    $results = $query['hits']['hits'];
  }

}

if(isset($results))
{
 $output .= '
  <div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table table bordered">
    <tr>
     <th>ID</th>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>CountryCode</th>
     <th>District</th>
     <th>Population</th>
    </tr>
 ';
 foreach($results as $r)
 {
  $output .= '
   <tr>
    <td>'.$r['_id'].'</td>
    <td>'.$r['_source']['name'].'</td>
    <td>'.$r['_source']['countrycode'].'</td>
    <td>'.$r['_source']['district'].'</td>
    <td>'.$r['_source']['population'].'</td>
   </tr>
  ';
 }
 echo $output;
}
else
{
 echo 'Data Not Found';
}

?>
```

When I search for any string, It successfully prints the Headers of the table but is not printing a data. What is the issue here?
The JSON format of the index is this:

```
{
  "_index": "cities",
  "_type": "city",
  "_id": "35",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 0,
  "_source": {
    "id": 35,
    "@timestamp": "2020-03-10T18:24:46.963Z",
    "@version": "1",
    "population": 2168000,
    "district": "Alger",
    "countrycode": "DZA",
    "name": "Alger"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2020-03-10T18:24:46.963Z"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed the 'population' field from the search fields and it worked. Elasticsearch here could not search numeric input and from a numerical field.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON format shows the data returned is an object. 
To access object values code the following:

```
foreach($results as $r)
{
 $output .= '
 <tr>
<td>'.$r->_id.'</td>
<td>'.$r->_source->name.'</td>
<td>'.$r->_source->countrycode.'</td>
<td>'.$r->_source->district.'</td>
<td>'.$r->_source->population.'</td>
</tr>
';
}
```

As you can see I used -> (Object) instead of [] (array)

Comment: the previous code worked just fine, once I removed the 'population' field to be searched. thank you for your efforts though @DanielKanis.